# Php Redirect to a file

Tags: php, redirect, unity-game-engine

To say it simply, I am trying send a requested file to my user using a php request.

I did try to redirect my user directly to the file using

`header("Location: http://myurl");`

But, I am using Unity and apparently, this redirection doesn't act the same as if I go directly to the right url.

I get this error : `necessary data rewind wasn't possible`

Do you know another way I could send my files from the server to the client ? maybe with an "echo" ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not really an expert in this area , but you might want to have a look at the new UnityWebRequest system which provides a LLAPI and a HLAPI which would help you to work around the issue, although I think this should be solved by design when you use the UnityWebRequest.GetResponseHeaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Or using javascript

```
<?php echo '<script>window.location="yoururl";</script>;' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did it with a simple

```
readfile("$ResourceId");
```

Thanks for your help, it makes me found it :)